# The require() method doesn't work when I use the received prop in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```jsx
import React from "react";

const ProjectCard = (props) => { 

    const {title , context, thumbnail, date, skillset, website} = props;
    console.log(thumbnail == "../assets/project1.png") # renders to be true
    return (
        <section id="">
            <div className="card" style={{width: '18rem'}}>
                <img className="col-12" src={require('' + thumbnail)} alt=""/> # doesn't work
                <img className="col-12" src={require("../assets/project1.png")} alt=""/> # works
                <div className="card-body">
                    <h5 className="card-title">{title}</h5>
                    <p className="card-text">{date}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}

export default ProjectCard;
```

I'm trying to build a portfolio website and currently I am making a project card to hold the images and text. I'm importing the properties from my parent component which passes the path of the image into a src but for some reason when I try to use the prop thumbnail it doesn't work even when I concatenated but it works when I just have the path alone.

Can someone tell me why. Thank you so much

Comment: Are you using `react-scripts`, Vite or something else to build this (ie what is in your `package.json` scripts section)?

Comment: Typically the easiest way to include dynamic assets is to put them in the _public_ directory

Comment: I am actually accessing the image from a json file, where I have "thumbnail" : "../assets/project1.png". But let me see if  I can put the image in a public directory.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't answer the first question?

Answer (score 0):

Actually when we use "require", it expects a static path.

So when you're using `require("../assets/project1.png")`, it's working because you're providing a static path.

On the other hand, when you're using `require('' + thumbnail)`, it isn't working because `thumbnail` is dynamic, it's coming from the `props`.

To pass the "thumbnail" dynamically, just ensure the image you're importing, in parent component, are in the public directory.

Then you can simple pass the images as props.

Hope it helped!

Comment: I am importing it from a json file and one of the prop is thumbnail which links to where the png is located. And I am trying to access it with map to loop through all the elements.

{coding_project.map((project) => (
                    <ProjectCard title={project.title} context={project.description} thumbnail={project.thumbnail} date={project.date} skillset={project.skill_list} website={project.website_link}></ProjectCard>
                ))}

Answer (score -1):

Webpack handles static imports differently from variable imports. If you want to import files you can try this.

Top level import

```
import FilePath from "../../assets/images/img1.png";
```

then you can use it like

```
<img src={FilePath} alt="" />
```